# Not showing from folder

Tags: php, database, photo

So guys I have made a admin system which saves images to a specific folder with specific id according to rows in database.
The picture is in the folder but its not showing..

MY index.php CODe:

```
    <?php
    include 'admin/connect.php';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
        $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while ($row = $run->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id = $row['id'];


    ?>
    <img src="inventory_images/"<?php echo $id; ?> />
    <?php

}
?>
```

Comment: Do you intentionally have a `"` before the id?

Comment: Show us what is in your $row array please

Comment: try this `<img src="<?php echo 'inventory_images/'.$id; ?>" />`

Comment: I just didnt knew how to mix the html with php, can anyone tell me how can i join html img with php id?

Comment: @AhadAmanHunzai have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `"` before you echo the id and adding it at the end:

```
<img src="inventory_images/<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

(otherwise your image link is `inventory_images/"54` for example)